# Alamofire add parameter for API request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have been working with the Alamofire in swift to get a request from the Spoonacular Api.

I keeps giving me the error: "code = 0;
    link = "https://www.mashape.com/webknox/";
    message = "We're so sorry, something went wrong. If this error persists, please contact us.";
    status = 405;"

I have been searching all over and tried many things but nothing seems to return the JSON that I need to continue.

```
    func APITest(){
    let retrievedString: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "SpoonacularApi")

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "ingredients":"apples2Cflour%2Csugar&",
    ]

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "other":"limitLicense=false&number=5&ranking=",
        "X-Mashape-Key": retrievedString!,
        "X-Mashape-Host": "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com",
        "accept": "application/json",
    ]


    Alamofire.request("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/findByIngredients?fillIngredients=false&ingredients=",
        method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        switch response.result{
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            print (json)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your URL path have `fillIngredients=false&ingredients=`, and you give params `"ingredients":"apples2Cflour%2Csugar&"`. So at least your URL should have twice ingredients, URL being `...fillIngredients=false&ingredients=&ingredients":"apples2Cflour%2Csugar&` Doesn't seems correct. So I'd suggest to remove `ingredients=` on the path. Also, I'd may remove the `&` at the end of your params, and it seems that it's missing a `%` before the `2C` between `apples` and `flours`.

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with Alamofire, I never know what encoding to use (you didn't perhaps use the correct one), But I think that Alamofire may already percent escape the "," into `%2C` so `params` may be `"ingredients":"apples,flour,sugar"`.

Comment: Also, you define a query string in the "other" header field, which doesn't look correct.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the small errors you pointed out but it still does no return the JSON i want. I commented out the "ingredients" parameter and added it to the URL. Everything else seems to be working fine its only an issue when i add that parameter. I must be missing something so I'll keep looking

Comment: So it works if you put the param in the URL. So I'd try this: `let parameters: Parameters = ["ingredients":"apples,flour,sugar", "fillIngredients:false]`. And then I'd try different value there: `encoding: JSONEncoding.default`